# Why is my website contact form is not working?

Tags: php, html, forms, email, contacts

'Hi! We are 2 students from Argentina and we want to graduate ourselves in graphic design. It happens that they are asking us to make a fully responsive boostrap page, andwe need the page to have a simple contact form that actually works, that sends the info to the mail.
we use some template for the web and it actually looks good, but it seems that the form of our page isnt working at all. we got this message, because i think that the php is a resource that for working it needs to be paid. We really dont have the money to do it. We just want to recieve 1 piece of informaition from the form, so for example de client submits its email, and thats it.
But we couldnt make it work. Here is the error message. '

"Form submission failed!
Status: error"

HTML

```
<form action="forms/contact.php" method="post" role="form" class="php-email-form">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="¿Cómo te llamás?" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Mínimo 4 caracteres :D" />
                  <div class="validate"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Tu correo" data-rule="email" data-msg="Ups, poné un email válido" />
                  <div class="validate"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group mt-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Asunto" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Mínimo 8 caracteres :D" />
                <div class="validate"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group mt-3">
                <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" data-rule="required" data-msg="¡Contanos algo!" placeholder="Mensaje"></textarea>
                <div class="validate"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="mb-3">
                <div class="loading">Loading</div>
                <div class="error-message"></div>
                <div class="sent-message">Recibimos tu consulta!</div>
              </div>
              <div class="text-center"><button type="submit">¡Mandale!</button></div>
            </form>
```

AND here is our PHP

```
<?php

  $receiving_email_address = 'piolamultimedia@gmail.com';

  if( file_exists($php_email_form = '../assets/vendor/php-email-form/php-email-form.php' )) {
    include( $php_email_form );
  } else {
    die( 'Unable to load the "PHP Email Form" Library!');
  }

  $contact = new PHP_Email_Form;
  $contact->ajax = true;
  
  $contact->to = $receiving_email_address;
  $contact->from_name = $_POST['name'];
  $contact->from_email = $_POST['email'];
  $contact->subject = $_POST['subject'];

 
  $contact->smtp = array(
    'host' => 'example.com',
    'username' => 'example',
    'password' => 'pass',
    'port' => '587'
  );
  $contact->add_message( $_POST['name'], 'From');
  $contact->add_message( $_POST['email'], 'Email');
  $contact->add_message( $_POST['message'], 'Message', 10);

  echo $contact->send();
?>
```

Please help us recieving
THank you very much, as you can imagine we are very rookie

Comment: I assume you changed the host from example.com to a valid email server?

Comment: your libs api makes no sense, `$contact->from_name = $_POST['name'];` then `$contact->add_message( $_POST['name'], 'From');`? `$contact->ajax = true;`? you may need to add that class into the question

Comment: https://bootstrapmade.com/php-email-form/ FWIW

Comment: We didnt change the host example. Is it anyform i can use a free host instead of that?

Comment: I dont know what tou mean sory im really rookie

Comment: How can i put a free host, from this to work? Sory my lack of knowledge, we are studying graphic design, we can design a logo for your work for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code that other people addressed in the comments, but the most pressing one is that you need to have the credentials of an SMTP server to use to actually send the email

Since I see you're using GMAIL for the receiver, you can use GMAIL SMTP server:

```
$contact->smtp = array(
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'username' => 'piolamultimedia@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'your password',
    'port' => '465'
  );
```